# Android - BroadcastReceiver gets called unexpectedly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using broadcasts to check if the connexion switches between off to on and then upload some data to Internet. The problem it's that this broadcast gets called suddenly. I don't want to get it called at that moment. I don't know how can I 'lock' this broadcast at that moment.

Here's the code of my BroadcastReceiver class:

```
class Broadcast_Reciver extends BroadcastReceiver implements Variables {

    CheckConexion cc;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context contxt, Intent intent) {

        // Cuando hay un evento, lo diferenciamos y hacemos una acción.

        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Sms sms = new Sms(null, contxt);
            sms.uploadNewSms(intent);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW)) {
            // st.batterylow(contxt);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
            // st.power(1, contxt);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
            // st.power(0, contxt);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)) {
            Database db = new Database(contxt);
            if (db.open().Preferences(4)) {
                Uri data = intent.getData();
                new ListApps(contxt).import_app(intent, contxt, data,
                        intent.getAction());
            }
            db.close();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            cc = new CheckConexion(contxt);
            if (cc.isOnline()) {
                /*
                 * Database db = new Database(contxt); if (db.open() != null) {
                 * if (db.move() == 1) { new UploadOffline(contxt); }
                 * db.close();
                 */

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm registering the broadcasts on a Java file not in a XML file because it's a service.

Take a look at this code when i register it:

```
        Broadcast_Reciver r = new Broadcast_Reciver();
        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction(SMS_RECEIVED);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
        i.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
        i.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(r, i);
        IntentFilter apps = new IntentFilter();
        apps.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
        apps.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
        apps.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
        apps.addDataScheme("package");
        registerReceiver(r, apps);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want your receiver to be called, [unregister](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) it.

Comment: Well i would like it to be called later but not this time :)

Comment: then re-register it when you want it called later. you can unregister and register whenever you like.

Comment: How can I do it? I mean, I want to do it by Java. It's possible?

Comment: `Context.registerReceiver(...)` and `Context.unregisterReceiver(...)`.